# how do I fix the Error of (Unable to delete directory/ Failed to delete some children) in the (Build) When i run an app?

Tags: compiler-errors

when I press on the Run icon to run on my Phone i get an Error said
"Unable to delete directory 'C:\Users\1619057.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\2104b04f5f36c8991152f281775b66b6'
Failed to delete some children. This might happen because a process has files open or has its working directory set in the target directory.

- C:\Users\1619057.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\2104b04f5f36c8991152f281775b66b6\aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows
  "
  So what shall I do ??
  Note: It was working normally but one day; that's habbened and I couldn't run again!!!

[Here is a screenshot for the Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3ZeB.png)

Answer (score 0):

just go to your project file and open app folder and delete build folder and every thing will work fine